# Python: create dictionaries based of substring from keys

Tags: python

I have a dict `dictA = {'/run/xy':'foo', '/run':'bar', '/run/ab/cd':'baz'}`. Need to create two other dicts from this based on it's keys.
For example, `dict1` should contain only key value pairs with one slash in keys and `dict2` should contain only key value pairs with more than one slash in keys as below:

```
dict1 = {'/run':'bar'}
dict2 = {'/run/xy':'foo', '/run/ab/cd':'baz'}
```

I've tried the below code but getting some error:

```
dictA = {'/run/xy':'foo', '/run':'bar', '/run/ab/cd':'baz'}
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
for k in dictA:
  if len(k.split('/')) == 2:
    dict1.update({k,dictA[k]})
  elif len(k.split('/')) > 2:
    dict2.update({k,dictA[k]})

dict1
dict2
```

how to get this done?

Comment: "but getting some error" always be sure to specify what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings have a [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) method:

```
dictA = {'/run/xy':'foo', '/run':'bar', '/run/ab/cd':'baz'}
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
for k, v in dictA.items():
    if k.count('/') == 1:
        dict1[k] = v
    else:
        dict2[k] = v

dict1, dict2
# ({'/run': 'bar'}, {'/run/xy': 'foo', '/run/ab/cd': 'baz'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

dictA = {'/run/xy':'foo', '/run':'bar', '/run/ab/cd':'baz'}
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}

for k, v in dictA.items():
    num_slashes = len(re.findall(r'/', k))
    if num_slashes == 1:
        dict1[k] = v
    elif num_slashes > 1:
        dict2[k] = v
    else:
        pass

print(dict1)
print(dict2)
# {'/run': 'bar'}
# {'/run/xy': 'foo', '/run/ab/cd': 'baz'}
```